# MVC5 Razor Response.Write - text position

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, response.write

I am trying to add a label using Response.Write

```
<div>
    @if (ViewBag.Message == "1")
    {
            Response.Write(Html.Label("text"));
    }
</div>
```

It works, however the text shows on the top of the screen not in the correct position, did not have this problem in aspx views.

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `Reponse.Write()`.  MVC is not webforms, you should never use it.  Instead just use `@Html.Label(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of `Response.Write()` in MVC(MVC is not Webforms) ,just try this code :-

```
<div>
    @if (ViewBag.Message == "1")
    {
       @Html.Label("text");
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is easy and simple.

```
{
    Response.Write(Label1.Text);
    Label1.Text = "Your Label message here.";
}
```